# ManyToMany django field not working, not taking any input in POST request?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, manytomanyfield

I have 2 models - Module and Room. A module can have zero or multiple rooms and a room can be added into multiple modules. So, there is a simple many-to-many relationship between them.

But when I define it in my `module/models.py` file, it is not taking any input as `rooms`. here are my files -

module/models.py -

```
class Module(models.Model):
    module_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    desc = models.TextField()
    rooms = models.ManyToManyField(Rooms)
```

rooms/models.py -

```
class Rooms(models.Model):
    room_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    desc = models.TextField()
    level = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

module/serializers.py -

```
class ModuleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    rooms = RoomSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Module
        fields = "__all__"
```

module/views.py -

```
class add_module(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        module_serializer = ModuleSerializer(data=request.data)
        if module_serializer.is_valid():
            module_serializer.save()
            return Response(module_serializer.data['module_id'], status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(module_serializer.errors, status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

POST request body for creating a module in POSTMAN -

```
{
    "rooms": [
        {
            "room_id": 2,
            "title": "4",
            "desc": "22",
            "level": "2",
        }
    ],
    "title": "4",
    "desc": "22",
}
```

With this request, module is being created, but no room is getting added in it.

Can someone tell me why my rooms are not getting added while creating modules?

Comment: what about: read_only=True?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write an explicit serializer create method to support writable nested representations.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations

Example:

Given a RoomSerializer like this:

```py
class RoomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    room_id = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = models.Rooms
        fields = '__all__'
```

We explicitly set room_id in RoomSerializer, to avoid <room_id> stripped away from the input data, and a MultipleObjectsReturned raised.

```py
class ModuleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    rooms = RoomSerializer(many=True) # remove *read_only=True*

    class Meta:
        model = Module
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self, validated_data):
        rooms_data = validated_data.pop('rooms')
        module = Module.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for data in rooms_data:
            room, created = Rooms.objects.get_or_create(**data)
            module.rooms.add(room)
        return module
```

Comment: Thanks for the create method. But I'm still getting an error! When I give the input as shown above, I'm getting the error - "rooms.models.Rooms.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Rooms -- it returned 7!" When I tried to print data it shows that its not taking "room_id" from the input given. What should I do for that?

Comment: room_id it's an AutoField primary_key, by default read_only.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. It worked! Was confused over it for 2 days.

Comment: But now, if i try to create a room, then it is asking for room_id. It was supposed to be generated automatically. :(

Comment: you can use another serializer for create a Room.

Comment: I'm using Postman for testing the API. In POST request, raw-data works but in case of form-data, it asks to input 'rooms' in module API. Even though, I've blank=True for that.
Look at this problem link - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69447820/form-data-not-working-for-manytomany-field-django)