# form-data not working for ManyToMany field django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, manytomanyfield

I have 2 models - Module and Room. A module can have zero or multiple rooms and a room can be added into multiple modules. So, there is a simple many-to-many relationship between them.

In post request, raw-data input works, but not form-data.

module/models.py -

```
class Module(models.Model):
    module_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    desc = models.TextField()
    rooms = models.ManyToManyField(Rooms, blank=True)
    room_list = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank=True)
```

rooms/models.py -

```
class Rooms(models.Model):
    room_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    desc = models.TextField()
    level = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

module/serializers.py -

```
class ModuleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    rooms = RoomSerializerWrite(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Module
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        rooms_data = validated_data.pop('rooms')
        module = Module.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for data in rooms_data:
            room = Rooms.objects.get(**data)
            module.rooms.add(room)
        return module

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):

        # Updating rooms
        rooms_data = validated_data.get('rooms')
        instance.rooms.clear()
        
        for room_data in rooms_data:
            room = Rooms.objects.get(**room_data)
            instance.rooms.add(room)
        
        # Updating other fields
        fields = [
            'title',
            'desc',
            'thumbnail',
            'is_deleted',
        ]
        for field in fields:
            setattr(instance, field, validated_data[field])
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

rooms/serialier.py -

```
class RoomSerialize(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    room_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        model = Rooms
        fields = "__all__"
```

module/views.py -

```
class add_module(APIView):
def post(self, request, format=None):

    # Adding the rooms to module from room_list
    new_request = request.data.copy()
    room_list=[]
    if 'room_list' in new_request:
        room_list_data = list(new_request['room_list'].split(" "))
        for room in room_list_data:
            room_object = Rooms.objects.get(room_id=room)
            room_serializer = RoomSerializer(room_object)
            room_list.append(room_serializer.data)
    new_request.update({'rooms':room_list})

    # creating the module
    module_serializer = ModuleSerializer(data=new_request)
    if module_serializer.is_valid():
        module_serializer.save()
        return Response(module_serializer.data['module_id'])
    return Response(module_serializer.errors)
```

POST request body for updating a module in POSTMAN -

```
{
    "module_id": 2,
    "room_list": "1 2",
    "title": "4",
    "desc": "22",
}
```

Pls notice that while taking input of ManyToMany field - "rooms", I'm taking a string "room_list" as input that contains all the room_ids to be included.
This works perfectly fine when I take input as raw-data in postman, but when I use form-data, it shows -

```
{
    "rooms": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

What to do?

Comment: I wouldn't allow the client to send form-data in this case - keep it simple

Comment: I also need to sent some media files, so form-data is needed. :(

Answer (score 0):

Nested `serializers` don't work with `multipart/form-data`.
Please refer to the following issues:

https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/7650

https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/7262

Answer (score 0):

You can accept many to many fields as form-data using this approach.
Add '**room_ids**' to the ModuleSerializer.

```
class ModuleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    rooms = RoomSerializerWrite(many=True)
    room_ids = serializers.ListField(
        child=serializers.IntegerField(),
        write_only=True,
    )
```

Now in the form-data of postman you need to pass the id list in this format:

> room_ids[0] = 1
> room_ids[1] = 2

where `room_ids[0]` and `room_ids[1]` are keys and 1, 2 are values.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted "rooms" to be interpreted as an array in Django using FormData, what you can do is pass in multiple `rooms` fields, each with a different id into Django. Django will actually interpret this as a list and it will evaluate this directly and properly to a `ManyToManyField`.

So if you want to pass in data for the Model field:

```
rooms = models.ManyToManyField(Rooms, blank=True)
```

You can pass in the data:

```
{
    "module_id": 2,
    "rooms": 1,
    "rooms": 2,
    "rooms": 3,
    "rooms": ...,
    "title": "4",
    "desc": "22",
}
```

Full disclosure I have only tested this using Javascript with `FormData` objects and passing in the data through Axios.